# Append model output to pd df rows

Tags: python, pandas, append, pyomo

I'm trying to put `Pyomo` model output into `pandas.DataFrame` rows.  I'm accomplishing it now by saving data as a `.csv`, then reading the `.csv` file as a `DataFrame`. I would like to skip the `.csv` step and put output directly into a `DataFrame`.

When I accomplish an optimization solution with Pyomo, the optimal assignments are `1` in the `model.x[i]` output data (`0` otherwise).  `model.x[i]` is indexed by `dict` keys in `v`. `model.x` is specific syntax to `Pyomo`

`Pyomo` assigns a `timeItem[i]`, `platItem[i]`, `payItem[i]`, `demItem[i]`, `v[i]` for each value that presents an optimal solution.  The `0807results.csv` file produces an accurate file of the optimal assignments showing the value of `timeItem[i]`, `platItem[i]`, `payItem[i]`, `demItem[i]`, `v[i]` for each valid assignment in the optimal solution.

When `model.x[i]` is `1`, how can I get `timeItem[i]`, `platItem[i]`, `payItem[i]`,  `demItem[i]`, `v[i]` directly into a `DataFrame`?  Your assistance is greatly appreciated. My current code is below.

```
index=sorted(v.keys())
with open('0807results.csv', 'w') as f:
    for i in index:
        if value(model.x[i])>0:
            f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n"%(timeItem[i],platItem[i],payItem[i], demItem[i],v[i]))

from pandas import read_csv      
now = datetime.datetime.now()
dtg=(now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M"))
df = read_csv('0807results.csv')
df.columns = ['Time', 'Platform','Payload','DemandType','Value']
# convert payload types to string so not summed 
df['Payload'] = df['Payload'].astype(str)
df = df.sort_values('Time')
df.to_csv('results'+(dtg)+'.csv')
# do stats & visualization with pandas df
```

Comment: I don't see `timeItem`, `platItem`, `payItem`, or `demItem` defined before you try to write them; are they?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is in the `timeItem` etc iterables from the code you've posted.  However, I suspect that something similar to:

```
import pandas as pd
results = pd.DataFrame([timeItem, platItem, payItem, demItem, v], index=["time", "plat", "pay", "dem", "v"]).T
```

Will work.

If you want to filter on `1`s in `model.x`, you might add it as a column as well, and do a filter with `pandas` directly:

```
import pandas as pd
results = pd.DataFrame([timeItem, platItem, payItem, demItem, v, model.x], index=["time", "plat", "pay", "dem", "v", "x"]).T
filtered_results = results[results["x"]>0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Scott!  I got some very good ideas from you, like including the 0's in a df & having it available to analyze.  Turns out the way Pyomo indexes the model.x output, I had to iterate using Qi Chen's method.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `DataFrame.from_records()` function:

```
def record_generator():
    for i in sorted(v.keys()):
        if value(model.x[i] > 1E-6):  # integer tolerance
            yield (timeItem[i], platItem[i], payItem[i], demItem[i], v[i])

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(
    record_generator(), columns=['Time', 'Platform', 'Payload', 'DemandType', 'Value'])
```

Comment: Thank you Qi Chen!  This has me going now & I learned a lot.  Nice touch to include the information about integer tolerance, I was unaware.  Your generosity is admirable and I'm very grateful.